# Category sidebar width in the category admin panel

Tags: admin, category, sidebar

Is there any way to widen the category sidebar on the manage categories page in the admin panel? My subcategory names are too long to display fully and with each additional sub level, less and less of the name is visible. Because many of my subcategory names start the same with only the last word being different, it makes it very hard to manage the subcategories without seeing the full name. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

add this to one of your custom css files:

```
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit #page:left {
    width:300px;
}
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit .div.main-col {
    margin-left:300px;
}
```

Adjust the width and the margin to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I've added one more rule to move divider between categories tree and main content

In `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css`

```
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit div.side-col {
    width: 260px; /* default 220px */
}
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit div.main-col {
    margin-left: 260px; /* default 220px */
}
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit .columns {
    background: url(images/side_col_bg.gif) repeat-y 257px 0; /* default 217px 0*/
}
```