# Category sidebar divider in the category admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, category, admin, sidebar

In the topic "Category sidebar width in the category admin panel" at [Category sidebar width in the category admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36239/category-sidebar-width-in-the-category-admin-panel) @Marius gave instructions to change the width of the sidebar and main section.

What CSS style or other source controls the position of the divider between the two? It would be helpful to move this too.

Comment: Are you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was facing same issue, now got it. It is an image added as background to class **columns**, you can adjust its position by changing value,
add this to one of your custom css files:

```
.adminhtml-catalog-category-edit .columns {
    background:url(images/side_col_bg.gif) repeat-y 297px 0; 
}
```

as shown in screenshot.

[image]